# Storing pointer from array value to original array index location

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am sorting an array and need to store a pointer from these values to the original index locations. What would be the recommended way to do this?

Simplified example:

```
float myArray[4] = {0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2}
std::sort(myArray, myArray + 4, std::greater<float>());
```

Results in:

```
{0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1}
```

Now when reading 0.4, I need to know that this is the second element in the first array. How would I go about this?

Comment: Create an array of references, and sort the references?

Comment: @JoelCornett I believe the standard forbids an array of references.

Comment: @Joel: to be exact, there is no way to create array of references, only array of `std::ref`s.

Comment: Use an array of pairs (actual value + index). After sorting the pairs (you can use `std::greater<std::pair<float,int> >` for that) you find the indices together with the sorted values in the array.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's what I meant, but thanks for the clarification. Really, I was referring to references in the conceptual sense. The reference could be a pointer, or a wrapper class of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought maybe create an array of pointers and sort the array of pointers (lambda). Not sure though if that is useful to you that way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    float myArray[4] = {0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2};
    float *myPointers[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        myPointers[i] = &myArray[i];

    sort(myPointers, myPointers + 4, [&] (float *a, float *b) {
        return *a > *b;
    });

    // myArray
    for (auto f : myArray)
        cout << f << endl;

    cout << endl;

    // myPointers
    for (auto f : myPointers)
        cout << *f << endl;

    cout << endl;

    // Check the address of elements
    cout << (myArray == myPointers[3]) << endl;
    cout << (myArray + 1 == myPointers[0]) << endl;
    cout << (myArray + 2 == myPointers[1]) << endl;
    cout << (myArray + 3 == myPointers[2]) << endl;

    cout << endl;

    // Indices of elements
    cout << myPointers[0] - myArray << endl;
    cout << myPointers[1] - myArray << endl;
    cout << myPointers[2] - myArray << endl;
    cout << myPointers[3] - myArray << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps if the efficency is not really a problem, you can just perform manual sort and use another array of "pointers" (which are not really pointers)
something like this:

```
int i, j;
float myArray[4] = {0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2};
int index[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    for (j=i+1; j<4; j++)
        if (myArray[i] < myArray[j])
        {
            fswap(&myArray[i], &myArray[j]);
            swap(&index[i], &index[j]);
        }
```

Comment: The idea is good, but reimplementing a sorting algorithm is not necessary. You can wrap the indirect access to `myArray` via indices in a comparison functor and pass that to `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to put something more like C++ here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Cmp>
vector<pair<T,size_t>> sorted_with_indices(const vector<T> &vec, const Cmp &comparator) {
    vector<pair<T,size_t>> sorted;
    sorted.reserve(vec.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        sorted.push_back(make_pair(vec[i], i));
    }

    auto cmp = [&](pair<T,size_t> a, pair<T,size_t> b) {
        return comparator(a.first, b.first);
    };

    sort(begin(sorted), end(sorted), cmp);

    return sorted;
}

int main() {

    vector<float> numbers = {0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2};

    auto sorted = sorted_with_indices(numbers, greater<float>());    

    for (const auto& el : sorted) {
        cout << el.first << ' ' << el.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```